# Probability of $X = Y$ for a bivariate pdf

Tags: probability

Can somebody explain to me why the probability of $X = Y$ is $0$ for a continuous bivariate pdf and not the integral of $f(x, x)$ over all possible $x$?

Comment: what is bivariate pdf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is integral 
$$
\iint_{y=x}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy,
$$
hence the (two-dimensional) measure is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Heuristically: The possible realizations $(X,Y)$ are two-dimensional. The subset $X=Y$ is a line, i.e. a one-dimensional manifold, with area $0$. And if $\forall x : f(x,x)$ is finite (no delta distribution), then the double-integral thereof is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral
$$
\iint_{\{(x,y):x=y\}} f(x,y) dx dy
$$is $0$ due to a general result concerning in measure theory: if $A$ is measurable and $\mu(A) = 0$ then for every measurable $f$, $$
\int_A f \ d\mu = 0
$$